# Selecting all dates record between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select all records from particular table between two dates.

Suppose two dates are `05-Nov-2015` and `25-Nov-2015`, then it will give me all records between above two dates - but if suppose particular date record among above date range is not there then it will not give that complete row, which I don't want.

The query should give me row with null values even if particular date record not found.

Comment: Add some sample input and output data.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I m using mssqlserver

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example:

```
select Date from TableName where Date between '2015/11/10' and '2015/11/13'
```